# How to set many records to new status in the same request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an API using Rails 3.2 and I am fetching messages for a user.
I need to set all the messages that I fetch to status read in the same request.
I am doing this right now, is there a better and faster way?

```
@output = @message.answers.page(params[:page]).per(10)
@output.each do |message|
 message.status = "read"
 message.save
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`messages.update_all(status: "read")`